# Android BlurMaskFilter

Tags: android, image, blur

Can anyone confirm that the Android [BlurMaskFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BlurMaskFilter.Blur.html) Method is based on Gaussian Blur (and not e.g. mean blur)? I'm really surprised that the documentation is not explicit here.

Answer (score 1):

In referencing the code [here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/include/effects/SkBlurMaskFilter.h), I can assume that it is based off of the Gaussian Blur method.

I completely agree with your documentation point, crazy to have to dig through the source for this info.